# Is it possible to fetch programming language of file from GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I am preparing Python script which will diff files from git commits log, and write difference into pretty printed html file.

I would like to color source code similarly to what is done on GitHub diff, and for that I would like to use [pygments](https://github.com/pygments/pygments). There is only one problem, it will need information about language in which source code is written, thus I must fetch it somehow.

I was wondering if there is possibility to fetch it directly from local copy of repository (preferred) or GitHub itself. GitHub is using [linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) so the work is already done why not use that? Moreover when we enter specific language link from below language bar information on GitHub UI interface you can clearly see all the files which were recognised as written in selected language.

I saw some information about `.gitattributes` file that you can set language for files in there, but I would need to set it manually, and after project update I would have to update that file with all added files.

Comment: I guess there is no git command. But you can use the github/linguist to get the language from a file. You can use it in your [application](https://github.com/github/linguist#application-usage) or at the [command line](https://github.com/github/linguist#single-file). Otherwise there are other repositories, for example src-d/enry, but the [python plugin](https://github.com/src-d/enry#python-bindings) is just work in progress.

Comment: @flaxel Thank you for your answare but as I wrote in the question this is not quite what I wanted to do. I've already went through many different solution till I found [guesslang](https://github.com/yoeo/guesslang). As they are using tensors it make me realize that language discovery isn't such a trivial task after all. That is why I am looking for solution which would allow me to read it stright from GitHub. I guess one solution would be just use requests and parse information directly from the web UI.
Moreover I want to perform this on many different clients for few to one repository.

Comment: GitHub does offer an API, which has a [method](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-repository-languages) to retrieve repository languages, but that won't get down to the file level so I'm not sure it helps here. The [contents](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#contents) API for individual files doesn't list it.

Comment: @SorenBjornstad Thank you for your comment but I already known about GitHub API and I was looking for a proper way to us it anyway. I wrote an answare [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64208743/6857902). It's quite bad actually but it works so I will probably just go with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon I finished writting this question I found GitHub REST API.
And even though I have not found function that could give me file language as is.
I figured out that it is possible to combine two GitHub REST API methods:

I will describe it below based on python implementation.

1. List all languages from project and store them into python dictionary
2. Iterate through repository languages and perform find with language parameter in the query (as the parameter q is required I decided that character which should be in any file is "space" thus we provide %20 as string we are looking for)
3. If total_count equals to 1 it means that we found our file with language provided we can return language name

```
import requests
import json


def check_file_lang(filename: str, repo: str):
    response = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/{}/languages".format(repo))
    lang = json.loads(response.text)
    for lang in lang.keys():
        response = requests.get("https://api.github.com/search/code?q=%20+filename:{}+repo:{}+language:{}".format(filename,
                                                                                                       repo,
                                                                                                       lang))
        search_result = json.loads(response.text)
        if search_result['total_count'] == 1:
            return lang

f = "Gruntfile.js"
r = "jquery/jquery"
file_lang = check_file_lang(f, r)
print(file_lang)
```

One problem with this is when repository have many language it is possible that this request could not be completed. As GitHub limits number of request per minute (unauthenticated==10 and authenticated==30) it is possible that to many request would be necessary to check all languages from repository. [GitHub REST API Rate limit](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#rate-limit)
Moreover even if repository have only one language it still takes 2 requests per file, meaning that you can check at most accordingly 5 or 15 files per minute.

Following that I though that it would be better to return all files from repository based on language provided but GitHub limits queries [GitHub REST API Timeouts and incomplete results](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#timeouts-and-incomplete-results) meaning for big projects your data could be truncated thus you couldn't know all files from repository.

```
def list_all_files_by_language(repo: str):
    response = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/{}/languages".format(repo))
    lang = json.loads(response.text)
    ret_dict = {}
    for lang in lang.keys():
        response = requests.get("https://api.github.com/search/code?q=%20+repo:{}+language:{}".format(repo,
                                                                                                      lang))
        search_result = json.loads(response.text)
        if 'items' in search_result.keys():
            ret_dict[lang] = search_result['items']
    return ret_dict
```

Solution has its flaws but it works. If someone would found anything better I am eager to try it.

For now I accept this answare because it fits my needs, as GitHub Enterprise (which is my use case) does not have mentioned limitations.